# how to fetch span tag value using yql

Tags: yql

I'm trying to fecth span tag value using YQL.

Here is my html code.

```
<div>
                <span class="pprice"> Rs. 50</span>
</div>
```

YQL which is being used is

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url="http://www.flipkart.com/women-extraordinaire-pb/p/itmdtafr7gazgkgv?pid=9788129131010" and xpath="//span[contains(@class,'pprice')]" & format=json
```

Above YQL returns
    `<span> Rs. 50</span>`

But what I need is just Rs. 50 without the span tags

Answer (score 1):

I never user yql, but it seems like XPath problem to me, try

```
xpath="//span[contains(@class,'pprice')]/text()"
```

or something similar...